# store file from guzzlehttp repsonse

Tags: laravel, file, guzzle

I want to save file from an endPoint API in `public` folder of my `laravel` app and I don't know how it works

code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api-sandbox.yousign.app/v3/signature_requests/{id}/documents/download', [
        'headers' => [
            'accept' => 'application/pdf',
            'authorization' => 'Bearer 00...........',
        ],
        ]);

        dd($response->getBody());
```

**Edit :**

after `dd` it shows this lines :

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#429 ▼
  -stream: stream resource @512 ▼
    wrapper_type: "PHP"
    stream_type: "TEMP"
    mode: "w+b"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "php://temp"
    options: []
  }
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}
```

Comment: Store response(encoded chars - consider it as text of file) as file `filename.pdf` , You can use Storage facade and file name should have extension as pdf

Comment: @DarkKnight I add  `Storage::put('demo.pdf', $response->getBody());` but I have an error when I open file from explorer

Comment: can you add `$response->getBody()` output to your question. I see `zip` in header, so please confirm whether you're getting pdf or zip from response.

Comment: So .. first try to debug your output. You were on the right track with your commented code. Laravel has something called dd(). `dd($response->getBody())` would be the first thing to do. Show that in your original question

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
return \Response::make($response->getBody(), 200, array('content-type' => 'application/pdf'));
```